# FCM - BatchAdd API returns 200 OK null response

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add FCM tokens to a topic in Firebase using [batchAdd API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server).

But, even if I'm getting `200 OK` response, the result I receive is:

```
{
  "results":[
    {"error":"null"}
  ]
}
```

What does this response means? Was my request successful?

Comment: Hi Sunil, please report the issue at: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ including the request you are issuing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to wrong processing of response. Everything is working as expected from Firebase server.